# Woocommerce SagePay Refference Number

Tags: woocommerce, payment-gateway, opayo

I'm working on a wordpress project for tours in UK and my client wants the payments to be done through SagePay. My problem is the following: 
I have to put a reference number to every single order with dates. So I made custom field into this dates, and for every date should be inserted a reference number. So they want to put this reference number into the "First name" field.

The question: How to get this reference number from the database and replace the firstname field with it? 
If you are used woocommerce sagepay plugin there is a file called `sagepay-form-class.php`. Firstname field is getting from database in row 720, so I have to get this reference number instead of first name.
 Default row is: `'BillingFirstnames' => $order->billing_first_name`, and should be something like: `'BillingFirstnames' => get_this_refference_number_from_database`. 
Thanks in advance.

```
$sage_pay_args_array = array(
            'VendorTxCode'      => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sagepayform_vendortxcode', $VendorTxCode, $order ),
            'Amount'            => $order->get_total(),
            'Currency'          => get_woocommerce_currency(),
            'Description'       => __( 'Order', 'woocommerce_sagepayform' ) . ' ' . str_replace( '#' , '' , $order->get_order_number() ),
            'SuccessURL'        => str_replace( 'https:', 'http:', $this->successurl ),
            'FailureURL'        => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sagepayform_cancelurl' , html_entity_decode( $order->get_cancel_order_url() ), $order_id, $order->order_key ),
            'CustomerName'      => $order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $order->billing_last_name,
            'CustomerEMail'     => $order->billing_email,
            'VendorEMail'       => $this->email,
            'SendEMail'         => $this->sendemail,

            'BillingFirstnames' => $order->billing_first_name,
                // Billing Address info
            'BillingSurname'    => $order->billing_last_name,
            'BillingAddress1'   => $order->billing_address_1,
            'BillingAddress2'   => $order->billing_address_2,
            'BillingCity'       => $order->billing_city,
            'BillingState'      => $billing_state,
            'BillingPostCode'   => $order->billing_postcode,
            'BillingCountry'    => $order->billing_country,
            'BillingPhone'      => $order->billing_phone,
            'CustomerEMail'     => $order->billing_email,

            // Shipping Address info
            'DeliveryFirstnames'=> apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sagepay_form_deliveryfirstname', $order->shipping_first_name ),
            'DeliverySurname'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sagepay_form_deliverysurname', $order->shipping_last_name ),
            'DeliveryAddress1'  => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sagepay_form_deliveryaddress1', $order->shipping_address_1 ),
            'DeliveryAddress2'  => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sagepay_form_deliveryaddress2', $order->shipping_address_2 ),
            'DeliveryCity'      => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sagepay_form_deliverycity', $order->shipping_city ),
            'DeliveryState'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sagepay_form_deliverystate', $shipping_state ),
            'DeliveryPostCode'  => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sagepay_form_deliverypostcode', $order->shipping_postcode ),
            'DeliveryCountry'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sagepay_form_deliverycountry', $order->shipping_country ),
            'DeliveryPhone'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sagepay_form_deliveryphone', $order->billing_phone ),

            // BASKET
            'Basket'            => strtr( $sage_pay_basket, $unwanted_array ),

            // Settings
            'AllowGiftAid'      => $this->allow_gift_aid,
            'ApplyAVSCV2'       => $this->apply_avs_cv2,
            'Apply3DSecure'     => $this->apply_3dsecure,

            // SurchargeXML
            'surchargeXML'      => $surchargexml,
            'ReferrerID'        => $this->referrerid
        );
```

Comment: This special number has to be created from date or he already exist? If already exist, is impossible for people to get it without accessing to your database. If it has to be created, how your client want it exactly?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thanks for your reply. I uploaded picture to see where is the refference number field. https://imgur.com/Uvp2rcK

This refference number however should be going here: http://imgur.com/zkXaBhA

So instead of 'BillingFirstnames' => $order->billing_first_name, I should have some function to get this refference number from databse.

BTW the table in database is called "wpeo_postmeta" and

Comment: I think you are using a plugin for "tour" booking in first screenshot (or not)… Because wpeo_postmeta has been created by some plugin, which one?. It seem like it's going to be complicated to retrieve a special reference of a product ID tour (with booking option) for that order ID in an external table, because without exploring your database and some relations inside it, how can we help you?… You have to update your question and give more details, about all plugins involved and some related database code for example for one order ID concerning a product ID tour… Your actual code doesn't help…